# How to connect a wordpress database with JDBC in google apps script?

Tags: wordpress, google-apps-script, jdbc, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to connect my wordpress database with google apps script jdbc.

Here is my code:

```
var connection = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://34.76.255.159:3306/wordpress", "wordpress", "DBpassword_found_in_wp_config.php_file");
```

I also tried with `localhost` instead of `3306`, and `localhost:3306` also ..

3 options lead to the same error:

> Fail to connect, check the chain, username and password ...

Where am I wrong?

Comment: If this is a website then I would could your  tech support.  They can probably help you to hook it up.  It's a common problem

Comment: I run this wordpress on google compute engine instance , with openlitespeed provider which installed everything on one click.
I can't find a way to get technical support from either google or openlitespeed.

If anyone could have more feedback it would be usefull

Comment: I added google-compute-engine to your tags perhaps that will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This is a bug

> https://issuetracker.google.com/119660771

In the V8 runtime of Apps Script the jdbc connector appears to be unreliable.

The workaround for this is to use the [Rhino runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_rhino_runtime).

Please go and star this issue to show Google that it affects you, and subscribe to updates that way too.